# Limiting Unity windows application's resolution

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, screen-resolution

I was hoping to grab some help with my problem. I want to limit my windows application window so it doesn't go under a certain resolution (example no smaller than 400x200).

I currently have logic that checks the current window size, and if its outside of a certain ratio, resize to target ratio. I can redo this logic but the problem with it is the window flickers between resolutions and its a little gross.

I want to mimic something similar to Unity editor or google chrome. There is a limit to when you try and resize the window so it doesn't go below a certain resolution.

Has anyone done something like this before and able to point me in the right direction? Sample code would also be welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer. 
Unity hard codes their min resoultion to 128x128. So in order to change it you need to subclass Unity's WndProc and override WM_GETMINMAXINFO window message: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-procedures?redirectedfrom=MSDN#winproc_subclassing

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be that you disable the Resolution Dialog (I suppose it already is) from the Player Settings and uncheck resizable window so you would pass 1 resolution at the game start using [Screen.SetResolution](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Screen.SetResolution.html) and that resolution remains unchanged (or editable through in-game settings).

Comment: This is what i was already using, but i get snapping if the resolution changes to below the minimum. Im trying to avoid that